# mysqli num rows issues

Tags: php, mysqli

This is the warning Im getting:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/snissa4/public_html/test.php on line 10

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user']))
{
    //variable declaration 
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    //connect to data base 
    $con=mysqli_connect("engr-cpanel-mysql.engr.illinois.edu","socialdrinkers_b","testing123","socialdrinkers_db");

    if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "Select * from Drinkers where userID = '$user' AND password = '$pass'")))
    { // correct info
        $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Drinkers where userID = '$user' AND password = '$pass'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
        {//cookie implementation
            $expire = time() + 60*60*24; //1 day
            setcookie('idNum', $row['idNum'], $expire); 
            echo "Logged in as <b>".$row['userID']."</b>";
        }
    } 
    else 
    { // wrong info 
        echo "<b>wrong id or pass</b>"; 
    }
}


echo "<form method = 'post'> 
Username: <input type = 'text' name = 'user'>
Password: <input type = 'password' name = 'pass'>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'LOG IN'> 
</form>";

 ?>
```

I am not sure why I am getting this warning, and when i try to login with the username and password i made in my database, it just keeps redirecting me to this page instead of giving the success message. I cannot find out why.

Thank you for your help, struggling with my cs411 (databases) class lol

Comment: you should really sanitize your input

Comment: This code is awful in so many aspects that I can't help but advise you to hire a professional to do the job. Or, if you are learning somewhere - abandon the class. They will teach you no good

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
  $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Drinkers where userID = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($user)."' AND password = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($pass)."'") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >0)
    { // correct info
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
        {//cookie implementation
            $expire = time() + 60*60*24; //1 day
            setcookie('idNum', $row['idNum'], $expire);
            echo "Logged in as <b>".$row['userID']."</b>";
        }
    }else{ // wrong info
        echo "<b>wrong id or pass</b>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query()` is returning false.  Try `echo mysqli_error($con);` -- that will tell you why `mysqli_query()` is failing.

As others have pointed out, your code is very vulnerable to SQL injections.  You should use prepared statements to fix that.

And as @viakondratiuk pointed out, you should rewrite your code.  Right now, you execute your `SELECT` query twice.  This just bogs down your script and will make it much harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from Drinkers where userID = '$user' AND password = '$pass'");
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

And of course don't forget about sql injections.

You can read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to avoid them.